# How do I move custom cells to left in editing mode in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have custom cells of UITableView which consist of UIImage and textLabel. When I select the editing mod, the textLabel shows the following image;

[image]

I want to move it to left. I tried all of things to do but it didn't work.
Please let me know.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allRows.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "editCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableView

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.allRows[indexPath.row].bname
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .left

    let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "group")!
    cell.imageView!.image = image

    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle{

    return .delete
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

   if editingStyle == .delete{

            self.allRows.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .fade)

    }
}

@objc func leftEditButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.tableView!.isEditing = true
    self.tableView?.setEditing(true, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: `cell.titleLabel.textAlignment = .left`

Comment: thank you for your comment, but textAlignment is not working :-|

Comment: Can u share code ?

Comment: Please refer to the above code :-)

Answer (score 3):

look at this, I hope it helps you:

[swipe left/right in tableViewCell](https://developerslogblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/28/ios-11-swipe-leftright-in-uitableviewcell/)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let closeAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Close", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
         print("OK, marked as Closed")
         success(true)
     })
     closeAction.image = UIImage(named: "tick")
     closeAction.backgroundColor = .purple

     return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [closeAction])
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dataArr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 80.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestTableCell") as? TestTableCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    cell.customImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_audio")
    cell.customTitleLabel.text = self.dataArr[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        print("delete at \(indexPath.row)")
    }
}
```

Here is the output for this code:

[image]

Note: You can change the editing action in `editingStyleForRowAt` method and for performing the action you need to write the logic in `commit editingStyle` method.

Hope this help you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wrote commit editingStyle instead of editingStyleForRowAt but still have a problem. There are some spaces between UIImage and textLabel.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create new label in that UITableViewCell and connect that label to custom UITableViewCell class ! then you are free to do anything !

### Swift 4 :

1. Create a new class which is subclass of UITableViewCell !

[image]

2. In your `storyboard` in right menu which called `Utilities` in toolbar of Utilities go to the `Identity inspector` defince your cell class to your new UITableViewCell class

[image]

3. Drag and drop `UILabel` from `Object library` into your cell

[image]

4. now using drag and drop connect that label to your `UITableViewCell` class then create an Outlet

[image]

Perfect !

now use myLabel instead of textLabel ;)

dont forget to cast your cell `as! YourCustomCellClass`

Good Luck ;)